# Ubercart conditional payment, no stock level data

Tags: ubercart

I have Ubercart up and running on Drupal 7 and I would like to add a condition to a payment. The condition would be that if one of the products in cart is currently out of stock, then won't let the payment method.

The problem is that there is no stock level in the data selector. How could I do this?